# How do you return values in column A if and only if same values in column B appear twice or more?

Tags: sql, oracle, count, conditional-statements, teradata

Say I have a set of data that looks like this...

```
Column A | Column B (Beverage)
Andres      Coffee
Erica       Coffee
David       Beer
Tyler       Beer
Tyler       Beer
Andres      Shake
Erica       Coffee
Erica       Coffee
David       Beer
David       Coffee
Tyler       Shake
```

I would like to return: Erica, David, and Tyler from Column A because each of the has had at least one kind of beverage twice or more (in Column B).

Answer (score 2):

This is an aggregation query:

```
select distinct t.cola
from t
group by t.cola, t.colb
having count(*) >= 2;
```

This is one of the very rare times when `select distinct` makes sense in a `group by` query.  You are not asking for the repeated value of column b -- you don't even want to know how many such column b's there are.  Just whether duplicates exist for any column b.